# chrome extension popup and background ajax

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a requirement where the background.html continous to update every 10 minutes and when I click on the popup it should trigger the background to update immediately and show the result in the popup.

I have the background updating using ajax working and I have the popup trigger the background to make an immediate update using ajax working as well. However, I am stuck on how to display the latest result in the popup...how can I tell when the background ajax call is complete and show the latest result in the popup?

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, if you want to listen for changes on the Background Page, you have two ways to do what you want.

1. In your Popup, you can register [chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest) in your Popup page, and in your background page you can [chrome.extension.sendRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest) when you get stuff updated.
2. You have direct access to the Popup DOM, you can get an instance from [chrome.extension.getViews({type:'popup'})](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews), and once you get that, you can just call a method in that DOM. From the popup, you can access the background page easily too with [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage). For both cases, you get a DOMWindow returned.

I personally would use #2 because you belong in the same extension process, you do not need to communicate to an injected Content Script.

```
var popups = chrome.extension.getViews({type: "popup"});
if (popups.length != 0) {
  var popup = popups[0];
  popup.doSomething();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to do chrome.extension.getViews(['popup']) but it gives me an error saying array not expected...

Comment: Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Expected 'object' but got 'array'.

Comment: You should always read the documentation, I didn't write code :) http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews  I have updated my answer with some code.