# can i call the function inside popup.js from background.js?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i want to access popup.js from background.js

this is my background.js

```
function abc(){

  //call function of popup.js
   xyz()
}

and this is popup.js 

function xyz(){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome extension popup and background ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306888/chrome-extension-popup-and-background-ajax) (see method #2 of the accepted answer)

Comment: thanks for your comment but it is not working in my case

i m getting popups.length is 0

Comment: That means that you the popup is closed.

Comment: yes my popup is closed. Actually i want to do this in background when i reload the extension, not after opening the popup. I dont know that it is posible or not.

Comment: You can't call a function in the popup when it's closed. Either move the popup's logic to the background page, or accept that the function can only be called when the popup is open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use chrome events

background.js: 
`chrome.runtime.sendMessage({yourMsg: 'Your Msg'});`

popup.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    //here you can call your popup.js function        
    xyz()
});
```